# Python POST (using requests) returns status code 200 but object is not created

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to run a Python script in order to process several POST requests (in order to create users for a system) using an array of user names. Everything seems to go smoothly and status code 200 is returned for every POST. However, the users themselves are not being created successfully after I check the system. I just want to check to see if my code is correct here:

```
user_list = []
user_names = open("Master_User_List.txt")
for line in user_names.readlines():
    user_list.extend(line.split())
user_names.close()

user_list = set(map(str, user_list))


auth_code = raw_input("please enter your authorization code: ")

user_names = user_list

for user in tqdm(user_names):

    url = "https://api.example.com/user?cost_id1234" 

    header = {"Authorization": auth_code}

    data_set = {"user": {"name":"bob123","code":null,"code2":null}}

    new_post = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data_set)

    print new_post.status_code
```

Thanks.

Comment: This does not get us enough context to actually be able to help you, please try to narrow down the issue into something more specific.

Comment: more context is needed. What is the actual api endpoint ? There are number of possible problems here

Comment: @eandersson I believe Mohammed may be right. Here is the response I get back from the post: {"response":{"error_id":"SYNTAX","error":"JSON decode failed","error_description":null,"service":null,"method":"POST"

Comment: You should post the actual data set in your question, as it is (or was at least) it was highly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is not a valid syntax, and in Python there is no `null`, but as an alternative you could define `null = None` on the top of your python code.

Use:

```
data_set = {"user": {"name": "bob123", "code":None, "code2":None,...}}
```

Instead of:

```
data_set = {"user{"name":"bob123","code":null,"code2":null,...}}
```

Comment: Looks like example code from the user rather than actual code, or at the very least this would never execute. So this can't be the issue as he is saying that he is reaching the print statement. Also, I didn't -1 your answer.

Comment: P.S your "correction" is still invalid, as there is no such thing as null or ```...```

Comment: @eandersson: Thanks for your intimation